# Plot 8 different pairs of (x,y) in a scatterplot using matplolib subplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have 8 different pairs of (x,y), like (x1,y1),.....(x8,y8), and I want a plot with 4 subplots (all be scatterplot) where the first subplot shows (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), the second subplot shows (x3,y3) and (x4,y4) and so on. I have used the following code and I have two problems with it:

1. it plots all the pairs in only one subplot
2. when I   want to add x label or y label for example to the first subplot and I use ax[0,0].set_xlabel("x1-x2") it returns "PathCollection' object has no attribute 'set_xlabel'"

The code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2,figsize=(12,12))
ax[0,0] = plt.scatter(x1,y1,color='red', marker = ".")#,order=order)
ax[0,0] = plt.scatter(x2,y2,color='blue', marker = ".")#,order=order)
ax[0,1] = plt.scatter(x3,y3,color='red', marker = ".")#,order=order)
ax[0,1] = plt.scatter(x4,y4,color='blue', marker = ".")#,order=order)
ax[1,0] = plt.scatter(x5,y5,color='red', marker = ".")#,order=order)
ax[1,0] = plt.scatter(x6,y6,color='red', marker = ".")#,order=order)
ax[1,1] = plt.scatter(x7,y7,color='red', marker = ".")#,order=order)
ax[1,1] = plt.scatter(x8,y8,color='red', marker = ".")#,order=order)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ax[0.0].scatter(x1, y1,...)` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you were declaring a subplot object (`fig`, with its subplots accessed via `ax[i,j]`) and then overwriting the access variable `ax[i,j]` by assigning it a regular `plt.scatter` object.

I can't explain why that made the program plot all the pairs in the same subplot (it *feels* like it should work) but nevertheless, using `ax[i,j].scatter()` should fix the problem, like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2,figsize=(12,12))
ax[0,0].scatter(x1,y1,color='red', marker = ".")#,order=order)
ax[0,0].scatter(x2,y2,color='blue', marker = ".")#,order=order)
ax[0,1].scatter(x3,y3,color='red', marker = ".")#,order=order)
ax[0,1].scatter(x4,y4,color='blue', marker = ".")#,order=order)
ax[1,0].scatter(x5,y5,color='red', marker = ".")#,order=order)
ax[1,0].scatter(x6,y6,color='red', marker = ".")#,order=order)
ax[1,1].scatter(x7,y7,color='red', marker = ".")#,order=order)
ax[1,1].scatter(x8,y8,color='red', marker = ".")#,order=order)
```

(this should also fix the `set_xlabel` attribute error as well)